# Is it possible to do a RegEx Find in Cream (VIM's derivative) via the dialogs?

Tags: vim, text-editor, cream

In Cream, I simply can't find the RegEx option mentioned on Cream's [info page](http://cream.sourceforge.net/featurelist.html)

```
Basic Features
* Find and Find/Replace dialogs use intuitive search, 
  with Regular Expressions as an option (Ctrl+F and Ctrl+H).
```

but the Find/Replace dialogs don't have a check-box or bullet-point to enable/disable RegEx.

I even tried using a RegEx in the Find-field, but to no avail.
  In the (Ctrl+F) Find dialog: e.*a
  ... does not find Zebra

Toggling into **Expert** mode does allow **VIM style** commandline searches, which are RegEx, but the Basic Features list says that RegEx is available via the dialogs.

Is it possible to do a RegEx Find in Cream via the dialogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precede the search term with `\m`.

Comment: Yes, this certainly works...  Thanks...  but it does bring up an interesting point... How to find "\m" via the dialog... "\\m" works but it means that the Find dialog has a **special exception**... I've also noticed the the Find dialog is aware of the **end-of-line** byte "\n" and tabs "\t" (etc?)... which means that a plain "\n" or "\t" need to us "\\n", "\\t" to fin them in the standard Find field of dialog... Unless this is a result of turning on &magic on, This is effectively a bug in a PLAIN text search.... http://www.mail-archive.com/cream-general@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00304.html

Comment: ... I guess it just meanst that Cream's Find/Replace dialog is "plain" text which is aware of  C-stye escape control characters... and a few VIM "backslash" commands...  I don't know all the VIM ones yet, but I am at least aware of it now... (I'm slowly getting to grips with it)...

Comment: If it's that annoying figuring out how to use it "the easy way," it may end up easier in the long term just to switch to straight vim :-)

Comment: This particular issue isn't so much annoying as it is mysterious and elusive. I've recenlty moved across from Windows where I worked with and around many software quirks .. I think the difference here (in Linux) for a new user, is the seemingly endless new things one has to learn (similar, but different). In Windows I learnt over months and years. Swithcing to Linux 100% has left me without many of my known tools, and I'm slowly finding suitable replacements.. As well as being rewarding, it is also quite demanding to get back to "auto-pilot".  I will try VIM and Cream (and Emacs) Thanks